# How to get Notification of Bool Variable set in setting bundle when my iphone application is in background?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have made one application in which i need background sync when user change the switch given in setting bundle.

I have used time , Local Notification but it does not work .
I want a notification that work in background and notify me when the switch value change in setting bundle .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the value from NSUserDefaults again. You can do an new thread that will check the NSUserDefaults value at some time interval.

Comment: I may be mistaken here, but would iOS allow your backgrounded app to run any threads at all?

Comment: Yes you can, just detach detachNewThreadSelector in applicationDidEnterBackground